# Pinwheel problems on my Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

How do I get rid of the spinning wheel and the flashing question mark? I have tried utility disk repair. I was unable to use the repair button because it is not a highlighted option. I have tried using my Mac keeper to get rid of the spinning wheel but it keeps coming back. What can I do about this problem that I am having?

Comment: That is a indication of broken boot sector. Your system can not find it. The best option is to restore the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting your macs PRAM. See http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222?viewlocale=en_US. If that doesn't work then hold <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> at startup to boot into recovery and then try choosing Macintosh HD as your startup disk.